# Populate column with number of substrings in another column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables "A" and "B". Table "A" has two columns "Body" and "Number." The column "Number" is empty, the purpose is to populate it.

Table A: Body / Number

```
ABABCDEF /
IJKLMNOP /
QRSTUVWKYZ /
```

Table "B" only has one column:

Table B: Values

```
AB
CD
QR
```

Here is what I am looking for as a result:

```
ABABCDEF / 3
IJKLMNOP / 0
QRSTUVWKYZ / 1
```

In other words, I want to create a query that looks up, for each string in the "Body" column, how many times the substrings in the "Values" column appear.

How would you advise me to do that?

Comment: By using a language other than MySQL

Comment: Write a function. Not solvable with pure SQL. Have a try, come back when you encounter problems.

Comment: I'm no programmer, but I'd say it's not a bad idea.

Comment: you can find out if one of value in body or not but i have no idea how to find out how many times it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the finished query; explanation will follow:

```
SELECT
  Body,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE (LENGTH(Body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Body, Value, ''))) / LENGTH(Value)
         END
  ) AS Val
FROM (
    SELECT TableA.Body, TableB.Value
    FROM TableA
    LEFT JOIN TableB ON INSTR(TableA.Body, TableB.Value) > 0
  ) CharMatch
GROUP BY Body
```

There's a SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0967/2).

Now for the explanation...

The inner query matches `TableA` strings with `TableB` substrings:

```
SELECT TableA.Body, TableB.Value
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON INSTR(TableA.Body, TableB.Value) > 0
```

Its results are:

```
BODY                 VALUE
-------------------- -----
ABABCDEF             AB
ABABCDEF             CD
IJKLMNOP
QRSTUVWKYZ           QR
```

If you just count these you'll only get a value of **2** for the `ABABCDEF` string because it just looks for the existence of the substrings and doesn't take into consideration that `AB` occurs twice.

MySQL doesn't appear to have an `OCCURS` type function, so to count the occurrences I used the workaround of comparing the length of the string to its length with the target string removed, divided by the length of the target string. Here's an explanation:

- `REPLACE('ABABCDEF', 'AB', '') ==> 'CDEF'`
- `LENGTH('ABABCDEF')` ==> 8
- `LENGTH('CDEF')` ==> 4

So the length of the string with all `AB` occurrences removed is 8 - 4, or 4. Divide the 4 by 2 (`LENGTH('AB')`) to get the number of `AB` occurrences: 2

String `IJKLMNOP` will mess this up. It doesn't have any of the target values so there's a divide by zero risk. The `CASE` inside the `SUM` protects against this.

Answer (score 0):

You want an `update` query:

```
update A
    set cnt = (select sum((length(a.body) - length(replace(a.body, b.value, '')) / length(b.value))
               from b
              )
```

This uses a little trick for counting the number of occurrence of `b.value` in a given string.  It replaces each occurrence with an empty string and counts the difference in length of the strings.  This is divided by the length of the string being replaced.

If you just wanted the number of matches (so the first value would be "2" instead of "3"):

```
update A
    set cnt = (select count(*)
               from b
               where a.body like concat('%', b.value, '%')
              )
```